# Finding person with most medals in Olympics database

Tags: optimization, sql, postgresql

I have an Olympics database from each Olympic year and I want to find the person that has won the most medals.  The main problem is that I'm basically querying the same sub-query twice in `SUBSET1` and `SUBSET2`. How would I go about making this more efficient?

```
Select athlete  FROM ( Select athlete, Sum(total_medals) as total_medals
from Olympics Group by athlete) as SUBSET1 Where total_medals = 
( Select Max( total_medals ) FROM ( Select Sum(total_medals) as total_medals 
from Olympics    Group by athlete ) as SUBSET2);
```

Comment: Can you add which database you are actually using (vendor/version)... SQLServer, DB2, MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Comment: Updated answer to include PostgreSQL

Comment: Rolled back Rev 8 to Rev 7. (Please don't edit questions  in a way that invalidates answers.)

Comment: @200_success: Why does Revision 7 invalidate answers?

Comment: @miracle173, because Malachi had already written *"difficult to read ... because ... the reserved words weren't capitalized"* (presumably meaning *upcased* rather than *capitalized*, but you get the meaning.

Comment: @TobySpeight I missed that this is codereview.stackexchange.com and not dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 11):

This alternative to @rolfl's answer is more readable, in my opinion.  It also has a more efficient execution plan.

```
WITH medal_count AS (
    SELECT athlete
         , SUM(total_medals) AS grand_total_medals
         , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(total_medals) DESC) AS rank
        FROM Olympics
        GROUP BY athlete
)
SELECT athlete
     , grand_total_medals
    FROM medal_count
    WHERE rank = 1
    ORDER BY athlete;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4e9c5/23)

Comment: In my experience, CTEs are slower than using a subquery since it is about the same as creating a temporary table (ie. you lose your indexes).

Answer (score 10):

In PostgreSQL, you can use the `rank()` mechanism to help.

It still requires a subselect, but consider the following query:

```
Select o.athlete,
       sum(o.total_medals) as sumtotal_medals
from Olympics o,
     ( select r.athlete as toprank,
              rank() over ( order by sum(r.total_medals) desc ) as rank
       from Olympics r
       group by r.athlete
     ) rankings
where o.athlete = rankings.toprank
  and rankings.rank = 1
group by o.athlete
order by o.athlete
```

I have put this in to [the SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4e9c5/16/0)....

---

Previous MySQL exampl

This can be done as top-count with a grouped select with a having clause.

```
Select TOP 1 athlete
from Olympics
group by athlete
order by Sum(total_medals) DESC
```

if you want the actual medal haul, add the sum to the select.

```
Select TOP 1 athlete, Sum(total_medals) as total_medals
from Olympics
group by athlete
order by Sum(total_medals) DESC
```

I have [put together a fiddle using MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/965db/2/0) (which has the LIMIT key-word)

Comment: Had a similar answer, but what if more than 1 person have the top-count?

Comment: Good question... @user35265 - what konijn says.... ?

Comment: If there is more than one athlete with the same medal count in my query I believe it would select all athletes with the medal count

Comment: The runtime of your new sql query is 66.962 ms while the runtime of my query is 38.919 ms.

Comment: @user35265 by the sounds of it, you need to be adjusting your expectations, 38 milliseconds is not 'slow', or inefficient... is there a real problem?

Comment: I just didn't like the fact that I was "basically querying the same sub-query twice in SUBSET1 and SUBSET2" - I felt like it was redundant.

Comment: @user35265 if you really need better performance on this query then you should consider a separate table with pre-computed aggregations ... perhaps a [materialized view...](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views) or a table that pre-aggregates the data....

Comment: Will definitively look into your suggestions

Comment: Materialized view is probably overkill. Check that you have good indexes first.

Comment: just for the record I +1'd the MySQL answer because I could read it and it looks like my SQL Server based Answer....

Answer (score 6):

I think that you are over thinking this,  in SQL Server I would do something like this

```
SELECT TOP (10) athlete  
FROM ( SELECT athlete, Sum(total_medals) AS total_medals
       FROM Olympics
       ORDER BY total_medals DESC
       GROUP BY athlete)
```

And then I would use my Reporting Software to decide if there are 2 or more people at the top.

This is probably more of what you want anyway, a top 10 list of all time.

---

**Side Note**

I found it rather difficult to read your query because it wasn't indented and the reserved words weren't capitalized.  I would recommend that you do those things when writing a query.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little late to the party, but I think you can make it less complicated.

Wouldn't this be what you need:

```sql
SELECT athlete
FROM Olympics 
GROUP BY athlete
ORDER BY SUM(total_medals) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Here is the obligitory [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4e9c5/35/0).

EDIT: Previous version didn't account for multiple people with the same number of medals.

```sql
SELECT athlete
FROM Olympics
GROUP BY athlete
HAVING SUM(total_medals) = 
(
    SELECT SUM(total_medals)
    FROM Olympics
    GROUP BY athlete
    ORDER BY SUM(total_medals) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

At a quick glance, the execution plan for this seems a little nicer than the other suggestions, feel free to correct me if I am wrong though.

[Here is the SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4e9c5/47)

Comment: This isn't correct because you could have more than one athlete that has the "highest" number of medals

Comment: @TheBear 
Thanks, I think I misread the question, I've updated the answer now.